# Registration of beating heart images

Tags: registration

I used the camera to take a series of timing pictures of the rabbit heart. Now I want let all the images register with the first image registration, so that the heart looks fixed. Are there any recommended methods? Or is registration suitable for this method? I have used itk-elastix for elastic registration before. But the texture features of the heart are distorted and appear inconsistent.
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGSae.png)
[other image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4fJz.png)

Now I want let all the images register with the first image registration, so that the heart looks fixed.